# lodash , convert string from svg circle (properties and values separates with space) to object for spread in react component inline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, lodash

I have this object, that is a svg definition:

```
  circle: [
    'cx="12" cy="12" r="8"',
  ],
```

I'd like to convert from:

```
'cx="12" cy="12" r="8"'
```

I mean an object  like this:

```
props = { cx:12, cy:12, r:8 }
```

it's possible with lodash or .. javascript modern ?

UPDATE:

Here my final component to draw svg in React with two best solutions.
I have a component to drawn a svg from a library what is a list of simple objects wit path, or optional circle, this svg component accept size and colors.

```
import React from 'react';
import iconlibrary1 from './iconlibrary';

// @Alexandrou solution:
const getConditionalProps = ( mystring ) => {
  console.log('my string');
  console.log(mystring);
  let result=mystring.split(' ').reduce(function(acc,item,i){
    let keyAndValue=item.split('=');
    acc[keyAndValue[0]]=keyAndValue[1].replace(/\D/g,'');
    return acc;
  },{});
  return result;
}

// @Nina solution:
const getConditionalProps = ( mystring ) => {
  return Object.assign({}, ...mystring
    .split(' ')
    .map(p => p.split('='))
    .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: +v.match(/\d+/) }))
  );
};


const ShowIcon = (props) => {
  const icon = props.icon || '';
  const color = props.color || '#000000';
  const size = props.size || '24';
  const boxSize = '24';

  if (icon !== '' && iconlibrary1[props.icon]) {
    return (
      <svg width={size} height={size} viewBox={`0 0 ${boxSize} ${boxSize}`}   fill={color} >
        { iconlibrary1[props.icon].circle && <circle    { ...getConditionalProps(  iconlibrary1[props.icon].circle[0] ) }  />}
        <path d={iconlibrary1[props.icon].path[0]} />
      </svg>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
export default ShowIcon;
```

here iconlibrary.js, where i define the svg images, with properties with path or circle

```
const iconlibray1 = {
  vpnkey:
    {
      path: [
        'M12.65 10C11.83 7.67 9.61 6 7 6c-3.31 0-6 2.69-6 6s2.69 6 6 6c2.61 0 4.83-1.67 5.65-4H17v4h4v-4h2v-4H12.65zM7 14c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2z',
      ],
      circle: [
        'cx="12" cy="12" r="8"',
      ],
    },
  exitapp:
    {
      path: [
        'M10.09 15.59L11.5 17l5-5-5-5-1.41 1.41L12.67 11H3v2h9.67l-2.58 2.59zM19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v4h2V5h14v14H5v-4H3v4c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z',
      ],
    },

};

export default iconlibray1;
```

This components are useful to show svg in native html, and not with  so you can change size, colors, in a simple way:

```
 <ShowIcon icon="exitapp" color="#FFFFFF" />
```

you can download free svg icons from :

https://material.io/icons

open the file, and just copy the main path(s), don't copy the last one, and circle if there is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a multi step approach where you split the string first by space, then the parts by equal sign and then reassamble the parts to objects and later to a single object.

It is working with

- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for getting a single object out of multiple objects,
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), takes an iterable and use the parts as parameters,
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), for mapping an element in a different value,
- [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), for getting an array with parts, who were separated by a given string,
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), for taking parts of an array or object,
- [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for dynamic creation of an object.

```js
var string = 'cx="12" cy="12" r="8"',
    object = Object.assign({}, ...string
        .split(' ')
        .map(p => p.split('='))
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: +v.match(/\d+/) }))
    )
    
console.log(object);
```

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai you are great

Comment: @Nina  \d+ - matches one or more numeric digits ,  what about if i need to work with string like 'cx="12e" cy="d12" r="8,2"';   I mean get all what is between quotation

Comment: in this case, take just `v` as value, or parse it with `JSON.parse(v)`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions can be using  `split` method in combination with `reduce`.

Use `replace` method by passing a `regex` pattern in order to remove `"` chars from your string. For instance, `"15"` will be turn into `15`.

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

You can also use `forEach` method instead `reduce`.

```js
let string='cx="12" cy="12" r="8"';
let result=string.split(' ').reduce(function(acc,item,i){
  let keyAndValue=item.split('=');
  acc[keyAndValue[0]]=keyAndValue[1].replace(/\D/g,'');
  return acc;
},{});
console.log(result);
```

---

**An alternate solution:**

```js
var string='cx="12" cy="12" r="8"';
var result = {};
var parts = string.split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i< parts.length; i++) {
  var subValues = parts[i].split('=');
  result[subValues[0]] = subValues[1].substring(1, subValues[1].length -1);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please let OP share effort. This promotes spoon-feeding

Comment: this solutions is nice, not easy for my lever, @Rajesh are you a frustaded in SO ? please don't bother, i'm building a large app mixing a lot of technologies, SI is not a play for me, and I use to programmate in JS 15 years ago, but the new JS and technologie not easy to me find solutions, so i'm not a newbie but I need help sometimes, it's not for SO this? or for moderators have a lot of time to judge

Comment: @DDave, do you want a more simple solution ?

Comment: @DDave Its not about your level. SO is to help people with their problems and not *get-code-for-free* site. So if you hit a problem, you should share your effort. That defines what you have tried and how far users should address in their answer.

Comment: it's ok, but i need wait 1 minute to accept the response (SO);  because have only 65 points

Comment: @DDave I have updated answer with very basic approach. Hope that helps you. But please remember to share your effort in question to avoid such discussions.

Comment: thanks for your comprehension, i like split and reduce, i did know nothing about that, i will study it , it's powerfull, thanks guys

Comment: i know classic solutions in javscript, but i did knew there are nice moderns solutions , so alternate solutions is something old school like i do , anyway thanks, first solution from @Alexandru-IonutMihai is modern what i' was looking for

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai what to do in the case, there are two valid answers, Nina solutions looks still  more modern for me, but i'm not expert on that , but dont want to offense your efforst  to change my favorite answer, what to do acccord SO rules?